# What is the difference between <? extends Foo> and <Foo>

Tags: java, generics

I seem to have a misunderstanding about the difference between `<Foo>` and `<? extends Foo>`. From my understanding, if we had

```
ArrayList<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
```

This indicates that objects of type `Foo` can be added to this array list. Since subclasses of `Foo` are also of type `Foo`, they can also be added without an error, as illustrated by

```
ArrayList<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
foos.add(new Foo());
foos.add(new Bar());
```

where `Bar extends Foo`.

Now, say I had defined `foos` as

```
ArrayList<? extends Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
```

My current understanding is that this expresses `some unknown type that extends Foo`. I take this to mean that any objects that are a subclass of `Foo` can be added to this list; meaning that there is no difference between `ArrayList<Foo>` and `ArrayList<? extends Foo>`.

To test this, I tried to write the following code

```
ArrayList<? extends Foo> subFoos = new ArrayList<>();
subFoos.add(new Foo());
subFoos.add(new Bar());
```

but was prompted with the following compilation error

```
no suitable method found for add(Foo)
method java.util.Collection.add(capture#1 of ? extends Foo) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Foo cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends Foo)

no suitable method found for add(Bar)
method java.util.Collection.add(capture#2 of ? extends Bar) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Bar cannot be converted to capture#2 of ? extends Bar)
```

Based on my current understanding, I can see why I might not be able to add a `Foo` to a list of `<? extends Foo>`, because it is not a subclass of itself; but I am curious as to why I cannot add a `Bar` to the list.

Where is the hole in my understanding?

Comment: [PECS (Producer extends, consumer super).](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/272324/31260)

Comment: `<? extends Foo>` is a *specific* and *unknown* class that extends `Foo`. An operation with this class is legal only if it would be legal for *any* subclass of `Foo`.

Comment: Wow. The more you learn about Java's generics, the more screwed-uppedness you find.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you have discovered by yourself, an `ArrayList` declared as `ArrayList<? extends Foo> subFoos = new ArrayList<>();` would not be very useful.

In order to see the usefulness of `<? extends T>` consider this:

```
List<Foo> collect( List<? extends Foo> a1, List<? extends Foo> a2 )
{
    List<Foo> collected = new ArrayList<>();
    collected.addAll( a1 );
    collected.addAll( a2 );
    return collected;
}
```

which can later be used as follows:

```
List<Foo> foos = collect( new ArrayList<Foo>(), new ArrayList<Bar>() );
```

or as follows:

```
List<Foo> foos = collect( new ArrayList<Bar>(), new ArrayList<Foo>() );
```

note that none of the above would have worked if the `collect` method had been declared as follows:

```
List<Foo> collect( List<Foo> a1, List<Foo> a2 )
```